# Issue with collisions

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

As you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q35X8.png), my character is flying.

The collision box is expanding 3 blocks on the left and the right, but the height of the collision box isn't expanding.

Here's my collision detection code:

```
    public bool Intersects(Vector2 texture1, Vector2 textureSize1, Vector2 texture2, Vector2 textureSize2)
    {
        if (texture1.X < texture2.X + textureSize2.X && texture1.X + textureSize1.X > texture2.X && texture1.Y < texture2.Y + textureSize2.Y && textureSize1.Y + texture1.Y > texture2.Y) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Block IsColliding(Vector2 position, float width, float height)
    {

        if (currentWorld == null) return null;
        foreach (Block block in currentWorld.blocks)
        {
            if (Intersects(position, new Vector2(width, height), block.position, new Vector2(block.texture.Bounds.Width, block.texture.Bounds.Height)))
            {
                ScreenManager.Instance.Draw(ContentManager.Instance.content.Load<Texture2D>("barrier"), position, new Vector2(width, height));
                return block;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: So, should the collision box height be expanding or should it remain at it's original size? It's not very clear what you're asking. I also don't see where the collision box gets expanded in the code.

Comment: i stopped using this math and since my game's map will never expand instead of using list of blocks i used a 2d array better performance because now i dont have to check every block for the collision and its super easy to detect collision

Comment: Sounds good to hear. Though, I'm not sure why you're showing code if you're not using it? Once again I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: i was using it before i realayized that i can use 2d arrays and the problem is that the player was flying because the math was incorrect or something was wrong but i couldnt fix it so i needed help

Comment: Read [this](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/). It's basically the best starting point for platformer physics out there, imo.